# Ma Crossover have a caddle of lag

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I want to build an algo that does the following:

When a price crosses up a 20-bars MA : buys
When a price crosses down 20-bars MA : shorts

Can you help me out?

```
//@version=3
study("My Script")
strategy("MA Crossover", overlay=true)

x = sma(close,1)
y = sma(close,20)

longCondition = crossover(x, y)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(x, y)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

Comment: dude ... just correct my code . you are just editing the post for points

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
strategy("MA Crossover", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = true)

x = sma(close,1)
y = sma(close,20)

longCondition = crossover(x, y)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(x, y)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```